# How to change selected values of conditional effects interaction plot in brms R

Tags: r, ggplot2, brms

I've created a graph showing the interaction effect between "Disp" and "mpg" using the mtcars dataset. I want to change the default values of 106.78, 230.72, and 354.66 to show a line for other values, for example the minimum of 71.1, maximum of 472.0 and a middle value of maybe 258.0. I'd also like to manually select 2 or 4 values rather than the default of 3. All code is included below with some borrowed from other related questions about changing axes or legend labels but nothing about the graph itself.

```
data(mtcars)

interactionmodel <- brm(vs ~ 1 + mpg + disp + mpg:disp, data = mtcars, family = bernoulli())

conditional_effects(interactionmodel)

##Creating individual conditional effects plots
the_plotstest <- plot(conditional_effects(interactionmodel),
                             ask = FALSE)

#final plot
the_plotstest[['mpg:disp']] + ## if 'mpg:disp' is the conditional to show
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) + ## e. g. an existing theme of choice
  ylim(0, 1) +
  labs(x = 'MPG',
       y = 'VS')+
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Disp") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Disp")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `plot_predictions()` function from the `marginaleffects` package. The package website hosts over 25 vignettes with detailed tutorials and case studies. These two might be particularly useful:

- Bayes with `brms`: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/brms.html
- Plots: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/plot.html

```r
data(mtcars)
library(brms)
library(marginaleffects)

interactionmodel <- brm(vs ~ 1 + mpg + disp + mpg:disp, data = mtcars, family = bernoulli(), backend = "cmdstanr")

plot_predictions(interactionmodel, condition = list(
    "mpg",
    "disp" = c(71, 258, 472)
    )
)
```

[image]

Disclaimer: I am the `marginaleffects` maintainer.

Comment: Thank you Vincent. This is almost what I want. I was able to change the axes and legend labels with the following: 'plot_predictions(interactionmodel, condition = list(
  "mpg",
  "disp" = c(71, 258, 472)
)
) +
  labs(x = 'MPG',
       y = 'VS')+
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Displacement") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Displacement")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)' but I'm unsure how to treat this as a ggplot object to change the linewidth without an aes() call. How can I do that with this method?

Comment: This is a tricky one because `linetype` must be supplied early on, and for that reason it is kind of "hardcoded" in the default plot. You could use `ggplot2::ggplot_build()` to modify the exiting plot, but that's probably more trouble than it's worth. The easiest strategy is probalby to call `plot_predictions()` with the `draw=FALSE` argument. This will return the raw dataset used for the plot. You can then feed that directly to `ggplot()+geom_ribbon()+geom_line()`, etc.